# Mapping the View Access Levels site content is using

Tags: acl

Is there any convenient way to discover what content is using specific Viewing Access Levels ?
I want to delete the Customer Access Level, in my upgraded to J3.3.0 website, but it gives the error message:

> You cannot delete the view access level '4:Customer Access Level'
>   because it is being used by content.

How to find where it is being used, throughout all the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no such tool to display all the access levels for all items throughout the website. So, someone will have to go through every component or in the case of following Lodder's answer through the db tables and search/filter for the items that have the Access level in question. 
In my case it was the example custom html module that demonstrate the Customer Access Level. Probably this website was initially installed with the demo content.

Answer (score 1):

If you to view the `#__content` database table using PhpMyAdmin or something similar, you will see each article on a new row. You will also see across the top the column names. The column name you need to look for is "**access**". If you scroll down, change every row with the access level of **4** to another value.

If you're unsure which number to change it to, go to view the Access Levels in the Joomla backend and each level has an ID. This is the value you need to change it to.

Hope this helps

Comment: I was hoping for a mass view tool throughout all the database. But it is ok now. I just found out that content. It was "Special!" module - with the half price on delicious oranges! - meant to be an example for the Customer Access Level. Thanks for the input anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ACL Manager might help with viewing all the access levels:

http://www.aclmanager.net/

The screenshots show a grid of components and categories. Not sure if it goes down to the article level.

Comment: ACL Manager gets my vote

Comment: I have ACL manager already installed, but unless I am missing something it doesn't handle the case of View Access Levels, rather it is showing the privileges by user/usergroup over items/extensions.